# Wrapper for Python Decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators

Lately, I have started using decorators more extensively. For a project, I require different decorators which I built like in the schema below:

```
def param_check(fn=None, arg1=None, arg2=None):
    def deco(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            #this is the only part that really changes
            result = func(arg1, arg2)


            return fn(result, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    if callable(fn): return deco(fn)
    return deco

def func(arg1, arg2):
   ...do something...
   .
   .
   ...return something
```

However, since this is a lot of repeating code I was wondering what would be the most pythonic way to build a wrapper function that only takes in a function, and then returns a new decorator? I tried several ways but had no success. I was wondering if someone knows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to add another layer: the outermost layer will take an argument, and that's what gets called inside `wrapper`, not a hard-coded reference to `func`.

```
def decorator_maker(decfun):
    def parameterized_decorator(fn=None, arg1=None, arg2=None):
        def deco(fn):
            @wraps(fn)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

                #this is the only part that really changes
                result = decfun(arg1, arg2)


                return fn(result, *args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
        if callable(fn): return deco(fn)
        return deco
    return parameterized_decorator


def func(arg1, arg2):
    pass

param_check = decorator_maker(func)

# Or...
# @decorator_maker
# def func(arg1, arg2):
#    ...

@param_check(3, 4)
def f(result):
    ...
```